# Is a theory with a prime model necessarily complete?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Based on what I see in available sources it seems that the answer to my question is "no". But I fail to see why. Here is my line of reasoning:

Consider a theory $T$ which has some prime model $\mathcal{M}$. For any two models of $T$ (let's call them $\mathcal{N}_1$ and $\mathcal{N}_2$) there are elementary embeddings from $\mathcal{M}$ to both $\mathcal{N}_1$ and $\mathcal{N}_2$. This means that $\mathcal{N}_1 \equiv \mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}_2 \equiv \mathcal{M}$ which shows that $\mathcal{N}_1 \equiv \mathcal{N}_2$. So any two models $\mathcal{N}_1$ and $\mathcal{N}_2$ of $T$ are elementarily equivalent, which means that $T$ is complete.

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Elementary embedding does not imply identity of models. See $(\Bbb N,S)$ and $(\Bbb N\sqcup\Bbb Z,S)$, for example

Comment: @Hagen: Where do you see "identity"? $\equiv$ is not $=$.

Comment: Why do you think the answer to your question in "no"? It seems to me that you have proven that the answer is in fact "yes".

Comment: @Hagen: Looks like I'm badly confused. Can you explain why $(\mathbb{N},S)$ has an elementary embedding to $(\mathbb{N}\cup \mathbb{Z},S)$? I thought the existence of an elementary embedding requires (among other things) that the two models have identical sentences. The sentence "There's a member that is not the successor of anyone" is true in the former model but not in the latter model. So there can't be an elem. emb. from one to the other. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mark: Because several online sources mention that every "model-complete" theory with a prime model is complete. I can't see why it also needs to be "model complete".

Comment: @Roozbehan Ah, then I understand your confusion. These sources probably define a prime model as something that *embeds* into every other model, then you need model complete to make sure these embeddings are in fact elementary. Note: I do not think this is the standard way of defining a prime model, usually the definition requires elementary embeddings in the first place.

Comment: @Roozbehan Just to confirm, your proof of why $T$ is complete is correct. If there is a model $M$ that elementary embeds into every other model of $T$, then $T$ must be complete. Usually we would call such a model a prime model, but apparently these sources you talk about consider a prime model to be something weaker.

Comment: Great! I just checked one of these sources and as you said they had a different definition for a prime model. Thanks a lot :) Maybe you should publish this as the answer to the question.

Comment: Just to clarify regarding $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\sqcup \mathbb{Z}$: I think Hagen von Eitzen was confused about what you wrote in your question. But he's right that the natural inclusion of $(\mathbb{N},S)$ into $(\mathbb{N} \sqcup \mathbb{Z},S)$ is elementary (note: here $\sqcup$ denotes disjoint union!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments below the question it turns out that the confusion was due to an unusual definition of prime model.

Usually we say a model $M$ is a prime model of a theory $T$ if it embeds *elementarily* into every other model of $T$. Using this definition we can indeed deduce that $T$ is complete. A proof of that is already given in the question itself.

So what was the confusion? It turns out that certain sources define a prime model as a model that embeds into every other model of our theory $T$. So in these sources this embedding may no longer be elementary. To be able to conclude that the theory is complete we need this embedding to be elementary. To fix this, one might for example add the assumption that $T$ is *model complete*, i.e. that every embedding of models is automatically an elementary embedding.

Comment: I've seen (and probably used) the terminology "algebraically prime" for the weaker notion of embedding (not necessarily elementarily) into all models of the theory.